# why am i getting Local variable 'employee' value is not used " for employee on line 7?

Tags: python, error-handling, pycharm, syntax-error

```
lstEmployees = []
lstNames = []
counter = 0


def export_employee():
    for employee in lstEmployees:
        with open("file.txt", "w") as output:
            output.write(str(lstEmployees))


def search_uen():
    uen = input("Enter employee UEN: ")
    for employee in lstEmployees:
        if uen == employee[1]:
            print("-----------------" + employee[0] + "------------------------")
            print("UEN: " + employee[1])
            print("Phone: " + employee[2])
            print("Email: " + employee[3])
            print("Salary: £" + employee[4])
            return employee
    return -1


def edit_employee():
    search = search_uen()
    if search == -1:
        print("Employee not found...")
    else:
        name = input("Enter the new name of the employee: ")
        uen = input("Enter the new UEN of the employee: ")
        phone = input("Enter the Phone number of the employee: ")
        email = input("Enter the email of the employee: ")
        salary = input("Enter the salary of the employee: ")
        search[0] = name
        search[1] = uen
        search[2] = phone
        search[3] = email
        search[4] = salary


def add_employee():
    global counter
    while counter < 5:
        print("----------------------------------------------------------\n")
        print("         Number of employee ({0:d})" .format(counter))
        print("----------------------------------------------------------\n")
        name = input("enter employee name: ")
        lstNames.insert(counter, name)
        uen = input("enter employee UEN: ")
        phone = input("enter employee phone number: ")
        email = input("enter employee email: ")
        salary = input("enter employee salary: ")

        lstEmployees.append([name, uen, phone, email, salary])
        if counter > 5:
            break
        else:
            continue


def print_employee():
    for employee in lstEmployees:
        print("-----------------" + employee[0] + "------------------------")
        print("UEN: " + employee[1])
        print("Phone: " + employee[2])
        print("Email: " + employee[3])
        print("Salary: £" + employee[4])


def menu():
    while True:
        print('-------------------------------------------\n')
        print('Welcome to the Employee Management System -\n')
        print('-------------------------------------------\n')
        print('[1] Add An Employee: \n')
        print('[2] View All Employees: \n')
        print('[3] Search Employees By UEN: \n')
        print('[4] Edit Employees Information: \n')
        print('[5] Export Employee Records: \n')
        user_option = input("Please select an option ")
        if user_option == "1":
            add_employee()
        elif user_option == "2":
            print('\n' * 3)
            print_employee()
            print('\n' * 3)
        elif user_option == "3":
            found = search_uen()
            if found == -1:
                print("Employee not found...")
        elif user_option == "4":
            edit_employee()
        elif user_option == "5":
            export_employee()
        else:
            print("Please select valid option...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

i have no idea what to do here,  on line its saying that the variable 'employee' is not used and i dont know why and when i switch the code to make the  add_employee function look like this: (see image)[code line 7 change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLA1h.png)

when i run the code i cant add employees and the string will always say 0 even after i have add details in.

other info: im using both latest version of pycharm and python sdk.

Comment: You don't have a `main` function defined in this code. You probably wanted to call `menu()` and _not_ `main()`.

Comment: you are a legend that fixed that issue. thank you very much i was pulling my hair out at that one haha

Comment: You have `for employee in lstEmployees:` but when writing to the file you use `lstEmployees`.  Please don't use posts as a "moving target" though - editing your code to fix the original error destroys the connection with the answer.  Better to post another question if you have a new error.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `main()` function but there's no **main** function defined. I think you want to use `menu()`.
Your `if __name__` block should look like this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

Your `export_employee` function never uses the `employee` variable in the loop. Every time you just write out the entire list of employees. Below, we open the file before we iterate over the list.

```py
def export_employee():
    with open("file.txt", "w") as output:
        for employee in lstEmployees:
            output.write(str(employee))
```

Comment: i made changes to the code and fixed the menu error and changed the code for the export_employee to                                                                def export_employee():
    for employee in lstEmployees:
        with open("file.txt", "w") as output:
            output.write(str(employee))                                                                                                    but now when i run the code when i try to add employees it doesnt update the string and just return 0 employees

Comment: I've edited to have the file opening _before_ you iterate over the list. Each you opened it, you were creating a new file before.